# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException ,on sor5.5.3

Tags: solr, solrj

```
2017-09-18 11:26:05.661 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:172.16.4.32:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be created
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [wyCluster_shard5_replica2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.run(CoreContainer.java:472)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core
```

There take some ERROR in it .

When I start the Solr slave, it being down soon.

It uses zookeeper.